Chinese movie about 3 separated siblings, oldest brother joins the gang to get revenge for parent's death
I'm looking for the title of a Chinese movie I watched in 2003.
Synopsis: There are 3 siblings (1 older brother, 1 sister and 1 younger brother) whose parents are killed by a gang? But the 3 siblings are able to escape. They go to an orphanage, and the younger sister and younger brother are adopted. The younger siblings go on to live a good/comfortable life. 
The oldest brother joined the gang to get revenge on his parents?
And somehow the oldest brother managed to save his siblings, and sacrifices his life to save them?

Sounds like the Hong Kong film Shou zu qing shen (AKA Reunion) from 2002.

When triad baddies kill their parents, the oldest brother gets his younger brother and sister out of the house and onto the street. They are eventually taken in by an orphanage, are adopted by different families, and grow up. Now the younger brother, adopted by a wealthy Shanghai family, is getting married to the girlfriend he met during his years abroad at university, and he wants his old siblings to be there with him. And so begins their quest to reunite after all these years, leading eventually to kidnapping and murder, while the older brother (grown up into Julian Cheung) does everything he can to keep his siblings alive, just like he did when they were little.

Pretty sure the older brother becomes a gang member. Here are some scenes from the film:




Oh my goodness. You are amazing!! thank you so so so so much! I really appreciate it!!
